# SQL Server : Transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do transpose data. The number of columns are not fixed(i.e. selected ShiftNames are not fixed). Here is my input data.

```
Date_time   ShiftName     Consumption
28-07-2016  Shift 1       20
28-07-2016  Shift 2       21
28-07-2016  Shift 3       22
29-07-2016  Shift 1       30
29-07-2016  Shift 2       31
29-07-2016  Shift 3       32
30-07-2016  Shift 1       40
30-07-2016  Shift 2       41
30-07-2016  Shift 3       42
```

And the output will be like this

```
Shift 1      Shift 2    Shift 3   Date_Time
20           21         23        28-07-2016
30           31         32        29-07-2016
40           41         42        30-07-2016
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Google "pivot query SQL" for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an pivot. Here is an example:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(Date_time varchar(100), ShiftName VARCHAR(100),    Consumption INT)

INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES
('28-07-2016','Shift 1',20),
('28-07-2016','Shift 2',21),
('28-07-2016','Shift 3',22),
('29-07-2016','Shift 1',30),
('29-07-2016','Shift 2',31),
('29-07-2016','Shift 3',32),
('30-07-2016','Shift 1',40),
('30-07-2016','Shift 2',41),
('30-07-2016','Shift 3',42)
```

Pivot:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Date_time,
        ShiftName,
        Consumption
    FROM
        @temp
) AS sourceTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Consumption)
    FOR ShiftName IN ([Shift 1],[Shift 2],[Shift 3])
) AS pvt
```

**Result:**

```
Date_time     Shift 1   Shift 2   Shift 3
28-07-2016    20        21        22
29-07-2016    30        31        32
30-07-2016    40        41        42
```

**Reference:**

- [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since the shiftName is dynamic,use this dynamic query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT 
 @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ShiftName )
 FROM 
#temp       
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT *  FROM   
 (
  SELECT * FROM #temp
  ) x  
PIVOT
(  
   Sum(consumption)
 FOR ShiftName IN (' + @cols + ')  
) p '

EXECUTE(@query);
```